# Unity - How to emit particles in 45 degree steps?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I recently found an nice app, which uses a cool cartoon like splash effect.

It Looks like this :

[image: Picture]

I marked it with the black arrow...

I tried to create it with the Unity particle System, but somehow i cant manage it to emit particles in 45 degree steps... In their Particle System UI isnt an Option for that.

Does anyone know how to do that ? Or is there an solution to do this through a script ?

Comment: If this is 2D, then it might be better to do this as a sprite animation :)

Comment: @Tom Yep its 2D ^^. I also thought about that. But im not a great artist to i hoped there would be an way to do this with the help of the particle system :D

Comment: I see! But an explosion as simple as that would not be too hard. You could even look online for ready made spritesheets!

Comment: rotate the particle system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Unity 5.6:

Create a new particle system. Set the following properties:

```
Looping: No
Emission
    Rate over Time: 0
    Rate over Distance: 0
  Add 1 burst:
    Time: 0.00
    Min: 8
    Max: 8
    Cycles: 1

Shape
    Shape: Circle
    Radius: 2 (or whatever value you want the minimum radius of the shape to be)
    Arc: 360
      Mode: Burst Spread
      Spread: 0.125
    Emit from Edge: Yes
    Align To Direction: No
    Randomize Direction: 0
    Spherize Direction: 0

Renderer
    Render Mode: Stretched Billboard
    Length Scale: 2
```

If you want to change how many particles are emitted, change Min/Max on the burst from 8 to X, and then set Spread on the Shape to 1/X, where X is the number of particles you want to emit.

To make longer lines, increase the Renderer's Length Scale and the Shape's Radius.

You may also want to play with the Limit Velocity over Lifetime module. I tried setting Start Speed to 15, turning on the Limit Velocity module and setting its Speed to 1 and Dampening to 0.125, which gave an interesting effect.

Comment: You are my hero ! Thanks a lot :) ! But there isnt a lenght scale at the render tab :/

Comment: So i somehow still got the problem that the emited dots dont "draw" a line like in the picture :/.

Comment: Setting the `length scale` is going to be what makes the lines instead of dots. Are you sure  you chose `Stretched Billboard` as the render mode? What version of  Unity are you using?